# My authors need to be able to preview their upload images and manipulate and scale

Tags: images, optimization

I am using a form and that form allows for IMAGE UPLOAD. After submission the form redirects and then they can see the reviewed post - however if the image which they uploaded blindly does not look good needs to be moved and scaled to best advantage how can they do this in the post. When I upload my profile pic to most apps I can place it and move it to best advantage within their mask - I want my users to do the same thing wither in the form itself ( ideally) or in the preview page.  Many thanks

Comment: Are you saying you'd like to load the WordPress image editor from the dashboard on the frontend, or are you asking for a plugin recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

i believe one way to do what you want would be to simply add an `action="post.php"` to your form. so the form redirect user to post.php onsubmit in which you can get the user input through $_POST

Comment: I don't think that's right. All three of the post.phps in WordPress are about handling blog post posts, not HTTP POSTs.

Comment: when talking about post.php i was talking about a custom file, the name can be whatever (just used post in reference to the comm method get/post)